# How to Avoid, Ajax button click twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

I am trying to insert data into the database using `ajax` call

> my problem is when I click the button **twice** the data is storing twice

and it is making me sick. How can I avoid it?

```
<from><button id ="GdStartTest"> </button></form>
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "gdcontroller.php",
    method: "POST",
```

And this controller:

```
$studentQuery = $conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_scores
```

Comment: `$("#GdStartTest").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();... rest of the code`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bind event only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408826/bind-event-only-once)

Comment: Lol re: "making me sick"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable the button immediately after clicking it and enable it within the ajax complete callback.

```
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){

    // cache the button reference
    var $this = $(this);

    // disable the button
    $this.prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url: "gdcontroller.php",
        method: "POST",
        .........
        complete : function(){
          // enable the button
          $this.prop('disabled', false);
       },
 ......
```

---

Or use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to execute the event handler only once.

```
$("#GdStartTest").one('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "gdcontroller.php",
```

Comment: I would rather put it in the "complete" callback so it gets executed no matter how the ajax call ended.

Comment: @Mike :  yes, that's a perfect way... I will update the answer... Thanks m:)

Comment: I don't get why - but the top method "disable" didn't work for me - I could always get 2-3 clicks to work. The "one()" method worked 100% for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many options to achieve this like, disable the button, put the event listener to off like:

```
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
    $("#GdStartTest").off();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable the button.
2. Use a Loader on ajax using beforeSend as another parameter.

   ```
      $.ajax({
              beforeSend: function(){
                  $(".loader").show();
              }
      });
   ```