# Event listener works multiple times for ajax driven html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**utilities.js:**

```
// on is used because html is dynamic
$(document).on('click', '#next_campaign', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

**layout:**

```
<script src="utilities.js"></script>
```

**view:**

There is a view that is loaded using `ajax()` on layout that contains `#next_campaign` button in it.

**The issue is, if the view is loaded n times then its listeners also works n time.** Means if view is loaded 2 times then the click on `#next_campaign` wil trigger the event two times so the output will be ***hello 2 times*** like :

> hello
>
> hello

Can some one please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Before down voting, let me know why?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: The explanation is already self explanatory

Comment: @MayankPandeyz While I didn't downvote, the downvote itself shows the **why**. It states when hovering over the downvote arrow *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* I'd assume who ever downvoted you felt that the question met one of those conditions.

Comment: @Fran: there is no issue if some one down votes, but please let me know why.

Comment: No it's not. Where's your ajax code? What does this load. Based on what you've written on should fire once. So your ajax call is obviously doing something to mess this up, but all you've said is, there is an ajax call. I can't replicate your issue based on the code you've added, so how can I answer without guessing?

Comment: @Liam: Zakaria gives me the solution :)
Some times a short description is enough to understand a problem by an expert

Comment: That seems to suggest that your really problem is that your calling on everytime you load your content. that's not how you should use on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent events from being bound multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968949/how-to-prevent-events-from-being-bound-multiple-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because in every load the click event will be attached, you could use jQuery method **[`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** to dettach the click event (if there's one) before attach it using `on()`:

```
$(document).off('click', '#next_campaign').on('click', '#next_campaign', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

Hope this helps.